# Default email address when user doesn't provide one

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm writing an Online RMA form for my company in ASP.NET.  They're very leery of asking customers for too much information, so all of the textboxes checkboxes, and dropdowns are optional, including contact information.  I don't think this is wise, but it's what they want to do.

I've written code to allow this, but I also want to nicely format the email I'll be sending with the user's email & organization if they provide it.  My question is, is there a "default" email address I can or should use to let my service technicians know that there is no email associated with the form?  I suspect the answer is just going to be something we agree on here in my company, but is there such a thing as a default no-user-input email address that "everyone" in the dev community uses?  Sort of like a "*lorem ipsum*..." type of entry as a placeholder for email instead of text.

Here's my code for making the decision:

```
    var orgName = dv_contactInfo.Rows[2].Cells[1].Controls[0] as TextBox;
    var orgEmail = dv_contactInfo.Rows[11].Cells[1].Controls[0] as TextBox;
    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage { From = String.IsNullOrEmpty(orgEmail.Text) ? 
        new MailAddress("No email specified") :
        new MailAddress(orgEmail.Text)};
        msg.To.Add("service@mycompany.com");
        msg.Subject = orgName != null ? 
            "Service Request from " + 
            orgName.Text : 
            "Service Request from unspecified organization";
```

Unsurprisingly, `new MailAddress("No email specified")` throws an exception because it's not in email form.  I also realize this isn't really a programming question, but I didn't even know how to ask the question to try to Google it.

Now that I've thought about it, I'll probably check the email and phone entries to make sure at least one of them is filled in, and pop up a Javascript Alert if we have no way to contact them to force them to give us a contact method.

Comment: See, you posted a question, then told us how you'll answer it. This isn't really a question any more is it?

Comment: sometimes vocalizing the issue to someone helps me figure it out too

Comment: _is there a "default" email address I can or should use to let my service technicians know that there is no email associated with the form?_ Yes there is: NULL.

Comment: @Jonesy, exactly so, sometimes it's just good to think out loud.  I frequently get myself into a situation where I don't have a good answer and start typing the question here in SO, and answer it while I am, and end up deleting the question because it's no longer necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a UX perspective, I don't think it's unreasonable to ask for contact information on an RMA form.

However, several notes on your original question:

- No, there is no *lorem ipsum* equivalent for email that is actually meant to be sent. You should never send a known bad value to a mail server.
- There is a precedent to use addresses like "noreply@google.com" to indicate that the address isn't intended for bidirectional communication, but that's not a placeholder; it's still a functional address.
- It's common practice to have catch-all inboxes for a domain. This is probably not applicable to your situation, but technically does allow sending to an address which doesn't exist.
- If you come up with a placeholder value, don't use an email address format. Otherwise, some applications will automatically turn this into a link and someone may blindly click it thinking that it's real.
- You could designate a special email address for *your* company to be copied in case the customer doesn't specify an email. In other words, you could notify an additional party within your company so that they could take action (if needed).

Very simple example:

```
bool usingDefaultEmail = false;

if( email == null ){
    // get an email for your service department
    ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["DefaultRmaEmailAddress"];
    usingDefaultEmail  = true;
}

// Logic here to append a warning to the body of the email that the customer
// didn't provide an email address. This way, someone knows that a higher-risk
// transaction has just occurred. They may also choose to contact the customer
// and verbally collect an email address.
```

Comment: Tim, thanks for the thoughts, I appreciate your time.  I agree with you & other folks that a placeholder value that's a valid email address isn't a good way to go.  I'm going to talk to the service manager and see if I can talk them into requiring at least one method of contact, either email or phone.  The service@ address will be monitored by about four people other than me (and I won't monitor it at all after the RMA is done), so as long as we agree on an appropriate value for the "From" text, we should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

You should conditionally check if the email exists before sending. It's bad practice to use a "placeholder" value.